# Magento layout update XML change impacting all pages

Tags: magento-1.4, magento

I'm trying to add a static block (which is actually a text link) after my site's home page only, by using the Layout update XML box on the CMS pages interface.

```
--------------
|             |
|   Content   |
|             |
---------------
|  Footer     |
|  Copyright |
---------------
| My Block    |
---------------
```

I've tried adding the block using this code:

```
<reference name="footer">
    <block type="cms/block" name="credits" after="-">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>my_block</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

The problem is: #1 that my block shows between the Footer and Copyright and #2: the change is visible on all the pages, whereas I only want it to show on my home page and not in the rest of the site...

Note: I'm running a Magento 1.4.0.1

Answer (score 1):

In order to display it only at your home page you have to add your XML under `<cms_index_index>`.

To adjust positioning use `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('credits') ?>` inside of your `page/html/footer.phtml`.

Comment: Did you mean I should enclose my XML with `<cms_index_index>` like this: `<cms_index_index> <reference name="footer"> <block type="cms/block" name="credits" after="-"> <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>home_link</block_id></action> </block> </reference> </cms_index_index>` ?

Comment: Yes. What file are you adding your XML at?

Comment: I'm not adding it to a file, but within the CMS page editor under the design tab from the Magento admin

Comment: In this case you don't have to wrap it into `<cms_index_index>` but it will be only applied to this particular CMS page.

Comment: That exactly what I want, but by adding this code the output is displayed on every single page...

Comment: Yes, how inded can we show it *only* on the homepage

Comment: Use `cms_index_index` layout handle.